# PsLoggedon - Unable to query resource logons

Tags: windows, powershell

Im trying to get info who's logged on the remote computer in our network.
I found thah the best will be PsLoggedon but it doesn't work. In powershell I type:

```
PS D:\> .\PsLoggedon.exe \\172.16.33.17

PsLoggedon v1.34 - See who's logged on
Copyright (C) 2000-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error opening HKEY_USERS for \\172.16.33.17
Unable to query resource logons
```

Where's the problem?
I would like to display user who is using remote desktop connection to that server.

I also tried this:

```
PS D:\> qwinsta /server:172.16.33.17
Error 5 getting sessionnames
Error [5]:Access is denied.
```

Any ideas?
Do I need provide credentials? if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

psloggedon requires Remote Registry Service.  I would check to make sure that is running.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "Unable to query resource logons" issue in Windows 11 by enabling and starting the Server (LanmanServer) service (which I had previously disabled).

That can be done in PowerShell with the following code:

```
If (Get-Service -Name 'LanmanServer' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue') {
   If ((Get-Service -Name 'LanmanServer').StartType -eq 'Disabled') {
      Set-Service -Name 'LanmanServer' -StartupType 'Automatic'; <# Default Value #>
   }
   If ((Get-Service -Name 'LanmanServer').Status -ne 'Running') {
      Start-Service -Name 'LanmanServer';
   }
}
```

(Enabling and starting the Remote Registry (RemoteRegistry) service (which I had also previously disabled)—as another answerer suggested—doesn't appear to have any effect on the issue.)